# How do I specify path to a C library in a rubygem?

Tags: c, ruby, linux, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to install [bouncestudio](https://rubygems.org/gems/bouncestudio) on a CI server. It depends upon a proprietary C library developed by by makers of the said gem.

The problem that I'm facing is that I do not have root access to the CI virtual machine and because of that I can not install the C library system-wide.

The rubygem has [a line](https://github.com/waseem/bouncestudio/blob/master/ext/bounce_studio.c#L2) its C extension code which is:

```
#include "BounceStudio.h"
```

So basically it references the C library in its source code. I can put the library in any other 'non-standard' place on a Linux machine but above line wont be able to find it and will result in an error at the time of gem installation.

Is there a way I can:

A) Specify the path to directory where C library is at the time of gem installation using bundler so that the gem installs successfully? OR

B) Perhaps modify the source code above so that it looks up for the referred library in a 'non-standard' place? OR

C) Any better idea?